# Slow instantiation of iTextSharp PdfReader with large fillable form

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have a large (6 pages, 222 fields) fillable PDF that I am using as a template with iTextSharp PdfReader.  When this object instantiates it takes 5 minutes or more.  I have tried:

```
string pdfPath = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/apps/ssgenpdf/App_Data"), "07-2011 Worksheets.pdf");
reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
```

alternatively I have tried reading the file into a memory stream and passing the memory stream to the PdfReader constructor.  Additionally I have tried using:

```
reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdfPath), null);
```

none of these alternatives show significant gains.

This is an ASP.Net app, and so my interim solution is to do this creation on application start and caching the reader, then I check to see if I get a valid reader from the cache and instantiate a new reader from that reader.  Now I routinely see under 50 millisecond response from this approach.

My concern is that this does not seem scalable if others in my group want to use this "fillable PDF as template with iTextSharp" strategy.  Does anyone have any suggestions for alternate strategies to balance performance with scalability?

Comment: Follow up to this issue. I have since done further testing in other environments. I created a console app on my workstation to do essentially the same task and it all took less than a second.  Then I found another web server to put this on, and there it also runs under a second.  Both web servers are Win2K3.

Comment: If that's the case, I would guess it's a server (load/other) problem. Any easy way to verify this is to create a simple test page on the problem web server that instantiates a PdfReader with a small, regular (no form fields) PDF file and see how long that takes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PDF you are using are same on the server as well as locally.sometime from source control they get corrupted.[I have face the issue with VSS with fillable pdf forms which i have created via nitro.]
Also better to ask the question and relevant forum [http://forum.pdfsharp.net](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/)

Comment: The [http://forum.pdfsharp.net](http://forum.pdfsharp.net) forum discusses PDFSharp and MigraDoc librairies **not** *itextSharp* library.